# How can i give message alert box in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net

**how can i give message box alert in asp.net** Webpage
By checking the username and password by membership in 'if' statement and in 'else' i should display the alert box as"enter valid username and password"(i checked the 'if' but i don't know how to give alert message in 'else')

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text))
           {

           }
           else
           {
               // Here i have to display message box alert
           }
```

Please  help me to solve this issue as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this...Add following code in your else part...

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"alert","Your Message",true);
```

Comment: thanks for reply. when we try this above code we got this below error. "The name 'ClientScript' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: ok...to do that on ascx you have to pass  extra parameter to ascx file of type `Page` and pass it value as `this` from where you caling can you do it than i can help u

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "msg", "alert('your message')", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this function for generic

```
public void MessageBox(string msg)
        {
            Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "err_msg", "alert('" + msg + "');", true);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Alert popup is registered to based on condition.

If you want to registered on Page load use this.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "msg", "alert('your message')", true);
```

If want to be registered any specific block use this.

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"alert","Your Message",true);
```